# What is this double pink/purple flower growing from a small potted plant?

Tags: identification, flowers

I cannot for the life of me track down the name of this flower.  Google image search wasn't much help either.

[image: Flower]

[image: Stem(s)]

Thank you!

Comment: Hi! Pretty sure this is a dahlia.  Does it have a bulb underground? Need to have a picture of the entire plant to be sure...

Comment: That's what I was thinking and it does indeed have a bulb underground, but I would like to know the specific variety of dahlia if possible.  Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, then we'll need a pic of your entire plant.  Include something for determining scale.  Do you remember where you got it?  Pretty tough to I.D. the variety on Dahlias, but hang in there.  There are people here that might be able to do just that.  A few more pictures would be helpful, however...!

Comment: OK!  I just got your new picture, that will help tremendously!  Thanks!

Comment: Great!  The only other thing I know about them is that they are all 'decorative miniatures'.

Comment: Good information, I'll give it a go, but I just know one of these experts on this site will actually raise these guys and be able to tell you exactly what it is...hey, thanks!

Comment: What company raised it? did it have a tag?

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't have a tag.  I got it from a local shop in Ohio that I don't have the receipt from anymore.  Sorry about the swing and miss on those ones, ha.

Comment: [Matching shutterstock photo](http://thumb1.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/209182/130127570/stock-photo-macro-image-of-a-garden-dahlia-flower-with-pink-streaks-on-petals-130127570.jpg)

Comment: It is a dahlia.. as pointed out by many others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possibly [*Dahlia* cv. Seduction](http://www.naturehills.com/dahlia-decorative-seduction) from group 5 (decorative).

> Decorative dahlias have fully double blooms showing no disc. The ray
>   florets are generally broad and flat and may be involute for no more
>   than 75% of their length (longitudinal axis) or slightly twisted, and
>   usually bluntly pointed

Reference: [dahliaworld](http://www.dahliaworld.co.uk/)

Answer (score 4):

That is a miniature [Dahlia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dahlia). Possibly the Decorative Dahlia Seduction. See BJY's answer for the details.